# Remove duplicates per row MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
| Domain | Owner   | Nameservers         |
__________________________________________
| Test1  | Person1 | Serv1, Serv2, Serv3 |
| Test2  | Person2 | Serv1               |
| Test3  | Person3 | Serv1, Serv2        |
```

My plan is to split the nameservers into own colums. (I need this structure for further import to a third party system)..

```
| Domain | Owner   | Nameserver1 | Nameserver2 | Namerserver3 |
_______________________________________________________________
| Test1  | Person1 | Serv1       | Serv2       | Serv 3       |
| Test2  | Person2 | Serv1       |             |              |
| Test3  | Person3 | Serv1       | Serv2       |              |
```

The empty spaces in the table could be an empty string or NULL.

I've tried the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_import_table AS
  SELECT domain, 
         owner, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX( `nameservers` , ',', 1 ) AS nameserver1,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `nameservers` , ',', 2 ),',',-1) AS nameserver2, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX( `nameservers` , ',', -1 ) AS nameserver3
```

But somehow i get the following result:

```
| Domain | Owner   | Nameserver1 | Nameserver2 | Namerserver3 |
_______________________________________________________________
| Test1  | Person1 | Serv1       | Serv2       | Serv3        |
| Test2  | Person2 | Serv1       | Serv1       | Serv1        |
| Test3  | Person3 | Serv1       | Serv2       | Serv2        |
```

As you can see the nameservers is being populated with the "previous" nameserver even if it's empty in the csv field. Can anyone help me get rid of/empty the duplicate values per row?

Comment: No, no, no, no. Use a separate table to store the relation between domain and name servers.

Comment: Exploding CSV in query with MySQL is ugly and complex.  You should get rid of that CSV and instead have a single record a name server and and the other side of that relationship.

Comment: I know the structure is horrible and totally against the rules, but i can't do anything due to the third party system :( (It's a wordpress plugin called formidable).

Comment: But that's no reason to repeat/magnify the error

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to abandon this plugin, but just for fun...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+--------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Owner   | Nameservers  |
+--------+---------+--------------+
| Test2  | Person2 | Serv1        |
| Test3  | Person3 | Serv1, Serv2 |
+--------+---------+--------------+

SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT DISTINCT domain
              , owner
              , TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nameservers,',',i+1),',',-1)) x 
           FROM my_table
              , ints;

+--------+---------+-------+
| domain | owner   | x     |
+--------+---------+-------+
| Test2  | Person2 | Serv1 |
| Test3  | Person3 | Serv1 |
| Test3  | Person3 | Serv2 |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many ',' in `nameservers`, then use if to separate it.

```
SELECT domain, 
         owner, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX( `nameservers` , ',', 1 ) AS nameserver1,
         IF(
            LENGTH(`nameservers`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`nameservers`,',',''))>0,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `nameservers` , ',', 2 ),',',-1),
            ''
    )AS nameserver2, 
         IF(
            LENGTH(`nameservers`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`nameservers`,',',''))>1,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( `nameservers` , ',', -1 ),
            ''
    ) AS nameserver3
```